# Placing new variable in specific position

Tags: variables, position, spss

I am computing a new variable in the SPSS syntax. If I execute the command the new variable shows up at the bottom of my list of variables. I want the variable between two already existing variables, let's say `v111` and `v112`.
How do I write this in my syntax?
I realize this might be a very simple thing to do but I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
add files /file=* /keep=YourFirstVar to v111 YourNewVar v112 to YourLastVar.
```

Shorter version:

```
add files /file=* /keep=YourFirstVar to v111 YourNewVar ALL.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried it but I get the error that the file name is not valid. I suppose I should give the name of the data file on * right? And this code will reintroduce the file everytime? I have to make a lot of new variables and want to place them on different places in my data file.

Comment: The * in the command refers to the active dataset, which should be the one you've been working on when adding new variables. You can add a "DATASET ACTIVATE YourDatasetName." before running the ADD FILES.

Comment: Instead of running this after every new variable, consider running it once after adding all the new vars (eg. keep=v1 to v15 Nv1 v16 to v46 Nv2 v47 to v130 Nv3 ALL).

Comment: Thanks this helped!

Answer (score 0):

You also needed to have defined the variable format you are introducing.

for example :

```
DATASET ACTIVATE DataSet1.
string M_1 (a254).
add files /file=  *
/keep = Firstvar to LastVar M_1 All.
exe.
```